# Predicting performance for an iPhone/iPod Touch App

Tags: iphone, performance, ipod, simulator

I don't have an iPhone Developer Program Account yet and will be getting one in the next couple of days. Can instruments be used with the simulator to give a rough estimate on how well my app may perform? Using instruments I checked and fixed all the leaks it was detecting, and it appears that my memory usage maxes out at about 5.77mb. Is there any other tests I could perform with instruments to judge how well my app would perform? I realize there is no way other then the actual device to get a definite answer, it would be nice to get an estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping memory under control is a good first step. Also, make sure you're not allocating too many objects, as all those allocations can take time (use ObjAlloc to check this; it can show you things that Leaks cannot).

Comparing performance between the Sim and Device is pretty much pointless... you have effectively unlimited memory can CPU on the desktop. Best wait until you get your app installed on an actual device.

Comment: With the ObjAlloc the most I use in my app is about 5.77mb, I think that would be a reasonable amount.

Comment: it sounds very reasonable. but there are often many differences between phone and simulator, i ran into quartz graphical glitches, massive variations in loading speed, etc etc.

you need to optimise with the device.

Comment: This is my first iPhone app, and is a simple 2d game using the cocos2d graphics engine. I probably should have gotten the developer account sooner so I could do more extensive testing, little nervous that performance may lag on actual device. But it shouldn't, even though their will be that doubt until I get the chance to test it.

Comment: ObjectAlloc is not the best source of memory usage information.  It can hide a lot of memory usage by views and other UI elements.  You want to examine the total memory usage of your application using the Memory Monitor instrument, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could test with a jailbroken device while you're waiting for your developer account. By the time you get your account, you would have time to fix any potential problems, and only need to recompile with your new credentials and deploy.